# .csv file import using sql bulkload or openrowset for missing column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp, openrowset

.I have a **csv** file. The data is given below,

```
___________________________________________________________
StateName       |  City                 |  Score1 |  Score2 |
________________|_______________________|_________|_________|
                |                       |         |         |
New South Wales |  Albury (C)           |  979    |   967   |  
                |  Armidale Dumaresq (A)|  987    |   985   |  
                |  Ashfield (A)         |  1015   |   1031  |
________________|_______________________|_________|_________| 
Victoria        |  Alpine (S)           |   987   |   970   |
                |  Ararat (RC)          |   951   |   938   |
________________|_______________________|_________|_________|
```

Now, I want to upload it in **`SQL`** via **`BCP or OPENROWSET`**. But the catch is for the records missing the state name, I want to copy over the initial declared state name.

For example, in **`row# 2`** above. I want the **`StateName`** to be **`"New South Wales"`** for city of **`"Armidale Dumaresq (A)"`**. How can I do it using **`sql bulk load`** ? I don't really want to create a new app only for this small thing. Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post fragment of your CSV file.

Comment: This is not something you would do with OpenRowset per se, you would load the data with the missing data using OpenRowset into a load table, and then copy the most recent state name down to any rows where its missing.

Comment: State,City,Score1,Score2
New South Wales,  Albury (C),979,967
,  Armidale Dumaresq (A),987,985
,  Ashfield (A),1015,1031
Victoria,  Alpine (S),987,970
,  Ararat (RC),951,938

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your csv file is saved as `E:\Temp\Test.csv`:

```
StateName,City,Score1,Score2
New South Wales,Albury (C),979,967
,Armidale Dumaresq (A),987,985
,Ashfield (A),1015,1031
Victoria,Alpine (S),987,970
,Ararat (RC),951,938
```

You can write [BCP format file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) in `E:\Temp\Test.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
 <RECORD> 
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="200"/> 
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="200"/> 
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="8"/> 
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="8"/> 
 </RECORD> 
 <ROW> 
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="StateName" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/> 
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="City" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/> 
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Score1" xsi:type="SQLINT"/> 
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Score2" xsi:type="SQLINT"/> 
 </ROW> 
</BCPFORMAT>
```

And use query:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) N, * 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'E:\Temp\Test.csv', FORMATFILE = 'E:\Temp\Test.xml', FIRSTROW = 2) As Blk
), NameGroup AS
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(StateName) OVER(ORDER BY N ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) GroupName FROM Src
)
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(StateName) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupName ORDER BY N ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) StateName, City, Score1, Score2
FROM NameGroup
```

**Result**

```
StateName         City                    Score1   Score2
----------------- ----------------------- -------- ------
New South Wales   Albury (C)              979      967
New South Wales   Armidale Dumaresq (A)   987      985
New South Wales   Ashfield (A)            1015     1031
Victoria          Alpine (S)              987      970
Victoria          Ararat (RC)             951      938
```

Comment: Wow' this was just awesome Pawel. Thank you so much for your help. Really really awesome scripting :)